# How does sphere hit equation expand to quadratic equation in ray tracing?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is probably very basic question but I can't understand how the first function is expanded to the second one?

A, B and C are vectors

$(A + tB - C) \cdot (A + tB - C) = r^2$

This should somehow expand to

$t^2(B \cdot B) + 2t(B \cdot A-C) + (A-C) \cdot (A-C) = r^2$

I managed to get the following by using distributivity of addition wrt scalar product, but can't figure out how to proceed:

$A \cdot A + 2t(A \cdot B) - 2(A \cdot C) + (tB-C) \cdot (tB-C) = r^2$

Comment: Use the distributive law on $(tB−C)⋅(tB−C)$, and you'll get $t^2 B.B - 2t B.C + C.C$. Then cancel stuff.

Comment: Sorry for being a total noob but I can't figure out how can I cancel something from the final line:
$A \cdot A + 2t(A \cdot B) - 2(A \cdot C) + tB \cdot tB - tB \cdot C - tB \cdot C + C \cdot C = r^2$
$A \cdot A + 2t(A \cdot B) - 2(A \cdot C) + t^2(B \cdot B) - 2t(B \cdot C) + C \cdot C = r^2$
Is there some other law used here or how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bring the $A$ and $-C$ terms together and treat them as a single term throughout. This is done because they are both constant terms, without a factor $t$.

$$(A + tB - C) \cdot (A + tB - C) = r^2\\
(tB + (A-C)) \cdot (tB + (A-C)) = r^2\\
tB \cdot tB + tB \cdot (A-C) + (A-C)\cdot tB + (A-C)\cdot(A-C)= r^2\\
tB \cdot tB + tB \cdot (A-C) + tB \cdot (A-C) + (A-C)\cdot(A-C)= r^2\\
t^2(B \cdot B) + 2t(B \cdot (A-C)) + (A-C)\cdot(A-C)= r^2\\
$$

It is basically like expanding $(1+x+2)^2$ by first gathering the constants to get $(x+3)^2$.